# How to get "mix-blend-mode" to work in this code

Tags: css

I am trying to modify [a fork from codepen](https://codepen.io/badpixel/pen/GqNPzK) to blend three animated circles (cyan, magenta, yellow) using `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` to achieve [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8qAn.png) where the overlay of all three colours is black.

As you can see on the codepen link, the blend mode does not work. Upon further research, I came across that `mix-blend-mode` needs to be within `<svg>` in order for it to work. As I am not a coder -I just understand enough to get myself into trouble- can you please take a look at the code and point out to me why the blend mode does not work as expected?

I have commented out the animation as I was trying to get the blending to work before fine tuning the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, mix-blend-mode does not need to be on the svg element, you can use it on all HTML elements. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

To achieve the desired result in your specific case, add `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` to .quadrant in the CSS section.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just so I can understand the code better, can you explain why `mix-blend-mode: multiply; ` did not work where it was?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with SCSS, but it seemed quite obvious to me that it should be in .quadrant as that is the class you would want to add the multiply blend effect to.

Comment: Thank you for your help!